# Why does iOS sometimes disable animations?

Tags: cocoa-touch, animation

I'm not sure what causes it, but I and others on my team have found that, for some reason, **iOS sometimes decides to completely disable all animations within our app**. iOS general animations (parallax, app switching, home button, etc.) are still enabled, so it's restricted to our app.

This wouldn't be so much of an issue if it weren't for the fact that it seems that some things like `-[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder]` don't work immediately after what would otherwise be an apparition animation (for instance, in a `viewDidAppear` method, or the block of a `-[UIViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:]`).

I've checked our code to ensure this isn't something we do, and indeed we simply pass `YES`s into the Cocoa Touch framework when it asks if we want things animated, and at no point in our code (or, as far as I know, in our 3rd-party SDKs) is `+[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:]` ever called. Likewise, I didn't do anything in iOS settings like "Reduce Motion", and simply restarting our app or letting the iOS device sleep will reverse this state.

So, **what might cause iOS to disable our app's ability to use system animations?** Additionally, **Does this affect how/when/if delegate methods and callback blocks are being called?**

Also, is there a way to detect, trigger, or reverse iOS's decision to disable animations?

Comment: i've noticed iOS sometimes does this when it is resource-constrained in some way (maybe low cpu or memory). I'd check your app in Instruments > Time Profiler and see what its usage is like.

Comment: @Nick the strange thing is that I tried to force this via recursive thread creation, making over 1900 threads all looping math for a solid minute, and iOS had no problem. Should I look to memory, maybe making a humongous heap to force this state?

Comment: Memory could be a good place to start, I'd verify what the app is doing now with the Allocations instrument. Also, it would be helpful to know what the app is for, does it normally do any resource-intensive operations?

Comment: @Nick Yes, it does. It's an industry app, not a personal app. That said, ideally, it should be the only 3rd-party app on the device.

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero Is your device JailBroken?

Comment: @Segev no; some of our 3rd-party libraries refuse to run on jailbroken devices for security reasons.

Comment: I've seen this happen too. Especially when working with `UITableView` and threads. I'm pretty sure it's a threading problem, but have never been able to figure it out exactly. One interesting experiment would be to call `[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES]` in a method that you know will get called. See if that fixes the problem (it did for me, so we just left it like that).

Comment: @notreallyJake I haven't encountered this problem in the past couple weeks, but I seem to remember trying that... if it comes up again, I will. Still would love to know how it'd get set to `NO`.

Comment: It sounds like something in your app modified the ui from a different thread than the main thread.

Comment: @replman Is that all it takes to force iOS to disable animations on its own?

Comment: It might put the ui in an inconsistent state where animations might not work anymore. If you modify the ui from another thread, anything can happen after that.